# In python, how to change the element data type of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

Working with python3.4.3 & psycopg2

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT
    somestring1,
    somestring2,
    float1,
    float2,
    float3
FROM
    table
```

I want to merge float1,float2,float3 into one single float[] then use `UPDATE` to get it back to database So I write the following:

```
res = cur.fetchall()
date = list(map(lambda x: x[0],res))
code = list(map(lambda x: x[1], res))
#vector = list(map(lambda x: list(map(float,x[2:])), res)) # this one works
vector = list(map(lambda x:x[2:],res)) # which won't work
res = list(zip(vector,date,code))
cur.executemany("""
    UPDATE mapped SET
        vector = %s
    WHERE
        date = %s AND
        code = %s
""",res) # error occurs here
```

The error message:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "vector" is of type double precision[] but expression is of type record
LINE 3:             vector = (16.25, 15.56, 16.07, 133.409279, 15.35...
                         ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

From error message my guess is that when `vector` is created it is created like some sort of `list<Any>` rather than `list<float>`. How can I do that simpler than cast every element to float with `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a list of tuples. A tuple is adapted by Psycopg to a record. You need to pass a list of lists as a list is adapted to an array:

```
vector = list(map(lambda x:list(x[2:]),res))
```

Comment: map returns a *map object* in python 3

Comment: @Moses Thanks, fixed.